# Is there a VB.NET equivalent of PrivateDBEngine from VB6?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

Hi I don't have experience with VB6 or VB.NET but am trying to convert some old code to .NET. The VB6 uses PrivDBEngine.

```
 Public oDbEngine As New PrivDBEngine
```

After some googling this looks like DAO. I was told to replace its usage with ADO.NET.  I pasted every spot I see it in the code below as a reference in case it helps. I'll get to googling "PrivateDBEngine DAO to ADO.NET" but if anyone knows of an equivalent in ADO.NET or even has some useful links please let me know. Should I be looking into DataSet? Thank you very much for your time and patience. Other places I encounter it are:

```
 ' Build the proper connection string.  If ODBC, the
    ' options line of the OpenDatabase method accepts the
    ' connection string.  If Access, just pass in the
    ' filename
    sPassword = Password
    Select Case ConnType
        Case DBTYPE_ACCESS
            DBFilename = ConnectString
            If (Len(UserName) = 0 And Len(Password) <> 0) Then
                DBOptions = ";PWD=" + Password
                sPassword = ""
            Else
                DBOptions = ""
            End If
            If (UserName = "") Then
                UserName = "Admin"
            Else
                UserName = UserName
            End If
            If (Len(SystemMDB) <> 0) Then
            --->  oDbEngine.SystemDB = SystemMDB <-----------
            End If
```

And also:

```
  ' Handle UserName and Password.
     Set oWorkSpace = oDbEngine.CreateWorkspace("Test", UserName, sPassword)
```

And lastly:

```
 Sub CleanUpDBConnection()

    On Error Resume Next

    ' Close the recordsets
     grsIndexTable.Close
     grsDocTable.Close

    ' Close the database
    If Connected Then
         DBConnection.Close
        Set DBConnection = Nothing
         oWorkSpace.Close
        Set oWorkSpace = Nothing
        Set oDbEngine = Nothing
        CurrentDTable = ""
        CurrentITable = ""
        Connected = False
    End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Do you still have working VB6 code?  If so, try to tease out what exactly `PrivateDBEngine` is - it sounds like it might be a class wrapper for the DAO engine, or possibly some Type someone got access to.  It isnt a stock Type in VB6 though (no hint of it in my registry even though I still do have VB6 installed).  If the DB remains MSAccess, then I'd use OleDB from .NET so you can use DataSets/DataTAbles, DataReaders etc.

Comment: I can find mention of `DAO.PrivDBEngine` but it appears to have been undocumented (looks like a method related to secured dbs), and non functional as of XP or perhaps as of Access 2000.

Comment: Forget about trying to convert the code.  Look at the functionality the VB6 code provides and then write the best VB.NET code you can to provide that same functionality.  When your aim is to convert you get stuck into looking for 1:1 correspondence between types and members and that is very unlikely to be possible.  It's also a good way to end up with suboptimal VB.NET code.

Answer (score 1):

PrivDBEngine is part of DAO. It's similar to DBEngine.

In an application, you may need to connect to multiple databases with different workgroup security connections. The PrivDBEngine lets you do that separate from DBEngine.

A common scenario is the main database (connected via DBEngine) which has data pointing to other databases, each with their own workgroup security settings. In that case, PrivDBEngine would be use to open those databases.

Off the top of my head, I can't remember if you can support 3 workgroup security settings at one time, but you can certainly reset the PrivDBEngine variable as needed without impacting all the recordsets already open using the DBEngine variable.

You should use the same ACE/DAO/DBEngine code in VB.NET if you are using Access databases. ADO can replace some ACE/DAO code, especially if you're using SQL Server and just retrieving data, but if you're using Access databases, ACE/DAO supports features that ADO doesn't.